# Does the Votes Cast counter update slowly?

Tags: support, voting, profile-page

The Votes Cast feature on my profile seems to be slow to update. Is it set to update every half hour or so, or is it supposed to update immediately?

It's a particular problem on the 'day', 'week', and 'month' counters.

Comment: Yes, it does.  It makes it more difficult to see who votes (on your posts) in real time. This is probably a good thing.

Comment: I see. That's just fine then.

Answer (score 4):

Almost, if not all, statistics calculation run on a scheduled job. Some jobs run every minute, some every 15 minutes, some on the hour, some once a day.

This makes that caching can be blamed if the numbers are slightly off, until that is no longer plausible.

As you may know, voting, specially up and down voting is anonymous. It is so anonymous that even moderators can't see who voted on a post. Still some users are desperate to find out who voted on their posts. In an effort to payback their gratitude they deleted their post and then watch for the reputation change  of the user they suspected to have voted on them.

While this is already error-prone without any delay in your actual vote counts, the added lag should make these kind of guessing not worth while at all.